# UnitControl - Block has encountered an error

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I am trying to use [UnitControl](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/unit-control/) in my custom Gutenberg block to define the line-height of text. I receive the "This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed" when I try to access the block in the WordPress editor. I am unsure what is causing this error. I've even tried removing references to the UnitControl in the return and save such as `lineHeight:headlineSpacing` to see if it would stop flagging the error. It still gives me the error so I am unsure if I am using UnitControl correctly at all or if perhaps I've made a mistake in the `<UnitControl>` element.

**CODE**:

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { 
    RichText, 
    InspectorControls, 
    ColorPalette,
    MediaUpload,
    MediaUploadCheck,
    Button,
    RawHTML,
    FontSizePicker,
    __experimentalUnitControl,
    InnerBlocks
} = wp.blockEditor;

const { PanelBody, IconButton } = wp.components;

registerBlockType('mycustomsite/small-jumbo', {
    //Built-in Attributes
    title: 'Small Jumbo',
    description: 'Block to generate a smaller jumbotron',
    icon: 'align-full-width',
    category: 'design',

    //Custom Attributes
    attributes: {
        title: {
        type: 'string',
        source: 'html',
        selector: 'h1'
        }
    },

    //Built-in Functions
    edit({attributes, setAttributes}) {
        const{
            title,
            headlineSize,
            headlineSpacing,
        } = attributes;

        const headlineSizes = [
            {
                name: '14px',
                slug: 'fourteen',
                size: 14
            },
            {
                name: '16px',
                slug: 'sixteen',
                size: 16
            },
            {
                name: '18px',
                slug: 'eighteen',
                size: 18
            },
            {
                name: '24px',
                slug: 'twentyfour',
                size: 24
            }
        ];

        //Custom Functions

        function onChangeTitle(newTitle) {
            setAttributes( { title: newTitle } );
        }

        function onChangeHeadlineSize( newHeadlineSize ) {
            setAttributes( { headlineSize: newHeadlineSize } );
        }

        function onChangeHeadlineSpacing( newHeadlineSpacing) {
            setAttributes( { headlineSize: newHeadlineSpacing } );
        }

        return ([
            <InspectorControls style={ { marginBottom: '40px' } }>
                <p><strong>Customize Top Text</strong></p>
                <PanelBody title={ 'Headline Size' }>
                    <FontSizePicker
                        fontSizes={ headlineSizes }
                        value={ headlineSize }
                        onChange={ onChangeHeadlineSize }
                    />
                    </PanelBody>
                    <PanelBody title={ 'Line Height' }>
                    <UnitControl
                        label="Line Height"
                        isUnitSelectTabbable
                        value={ headlineSpacing } 
                        onChange={ onChangeHeadlineSpacing }
                    />
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>,

        <div> 
            <RichText 
                key="editable"
                tagName="h1"
                placeholder="H1 Title" 
                value= { title }
                onChange= { onChangeTitle }
                style= { { fontSize:headlineSize, lineHeight:headlineSpacing} }
            />
        </div>
        ]);
    },

    save({ attributes }) {
        const {
        title,
        headlineSize,
        headlineSpacing,
        } = attributes;

        return (
            <div>
                <RichText.Content style={ {fontSize:headlineSize, lineHeight:headlineSpacing } } tagName="h1" value={title} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `UnitControl` is not actually defined anywhere:

If you look at the example in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/unit-control/), the `UnitControl` is defined as follows:

```js
import { __experimentalUnitControl as UnitControl } from '@wordpress/components';
```

I.e. It uses the `__experimentalUnitControl` component in `wp.components` and not `wp.blockEditor`, and secondly, it imports the component as `UnitControl`.

So you should also do the same.

And the equivalent syntax with the `const` keyword is:

```js
const { __experimentalUnitControl: UnitControl } = wp.components;
// I.e. const { <actual name>: <alias> }
```

So you should remove the `__experimentalUnitControl,` line in your code and import the one in the `wp.components` (or the `@wordpress/components` package) instead. I.e.

```js
// Change this:
const { PanelBody, IconButton } = wp.components;

// to this one:
const {
    PanelBody,
    IconButton,
    __experimentalUnitControl: UnitControl
} = wp.components;
```

And with that, the error "This block has encountered an error" would now be gone.

### Additional Issues in your code:

<del>You've made a typo in your `onChangeTitle()` code: You misspelled `setAttributes` as `etAttributes` and it will cause an error because `etAttributes` is not defined. :)</del>

<del>And secondly,</del> if you return an array of elements, then you should set a [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for each of the elements:

```js
return ([ // add a key for each direct child
    <InspectorControls style={ { marginBottom: '40px' } } key="foo-key">
        ...
    </InspectorControls>,

    <div key="bar-key">
        ...
    </div>
]);
```

Comment: This is a tremendously informative answer and I'm very grateful. Explaining the equivalent syntax to the const keyword was wildly informative for me. I only learned it that way and it stuck with me so understanding how those kind of convert really helped me comprehend the difference. Thank you!